# Is it logical to use a C# out, to pass a value to my controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I was asked to add something to my log on process in our .Net-MVC web app(scope creep) and while I was implementing I noticed that my controller is getting bloated. As a rule we try to keep our controllers very thin with most of our heavy lifting being done in the service. 
Here is what I am trying to do:

Service:

```
private bool IsLogonDisabled(out string enable, out string disable)
{
  try
   {
     enable = null;
     disable = null;

     DateTime enableDate;
     DateTime disableDate;

     string enableDateTime = (UnitOfWork.SystemSettingEntryRepository.GetItem(SystemSettingEntryType.SystemLoginEnableDatetime)).Value;
     string disableDateTime = (UnitOfWork.SystemSettingEntryRepository.GetItem(SystemSettingEntryType.SystemLoginDisableDatetime)).Value;

     if (DateTime.TryParse(disableDateTime, out disableDate) && DateTime.TryParse(enableDateTime, out enableDate))
     {
       disable = DisableDateTime;                              
       enable = EnableDateTime;                                
     }

     if (enableDateTime =="" & disableDateTime == "")
     {
       //compare the current date time with the window allowed  
       if (DateTime.Compare(disableDate.AddMinutes(-3), DateTime.Now) < 0)      
       {
         return true;    
       }
     }
     return false;          
   }

   catch (Exception ex)
   {
     OnServiceException(ex);
     throw;
   }
```

Here is my controller:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost] // if there is a system message display it.
public ActionResult IsLogonDisabled(enableDate, disableDate)
{
  if (!staffAuthenticationService.IsLogonDisabled())
  {
    return ValidateLogon( enable, disable);  
  }
  logon.ErrorMessage = ("System logins will be disabled at " + logon.DisableDateTime + " EST for system maintenance." + "System logins will be enabled at " + logon.EnableDateTime + " EST after system maintenance is complete.");
  return Json(logon);
}
```

What I am trying to do is to pass the values that I retrieve in my service method to this controller so that I can use it in the error message.

My question is this: is it logical to try to encapsulate this logic and pass it to the controller, normally I would save the model but in this case it is a transient model.

Comment: No idea what you're trying to achieve here. What do you see as being the use of using `out` parameters here? Not only that but you're not even passing any parameters in your controller... this doesn't really make any sense.

Comment: I am trying to output the string that I get in my service to my controller, so that I can use it in the displaying of the error message.

Comment: Also, just be careful about that bitwise & in your second if statement.  Behavior is the same now, but if you modify that at all, you might end up with unexpected behavior in the future (& has higher precedence than &&).

Comment: The code, as you currently have it, shouldn't even compile, because you're not passing any parameters to your IsLogonDisabled function (unless you have another override somewhere).  Pass your string variables to the function with the out modifier.

Comment: @dodexahedron In my project I have the out parameters on both enable and disable in the service, but Visual studio doesn't like the way that I am asking for them in the controller. I found a work around  by passing the values to the transient model and getting them from that in the controller. I was trying to avoid exposing the logonmodel to the controller. I am just wondering if it is bad form to pass values to the controller in MVC, I am used to seeing really thin controllers. Even having the error messages in this controller is bucking our design pattern

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you had a method in your service layer that returns a LogOn model, such as:

```
Class LogonModel

{
    bool IsValidLogin;
    bool IsLogonDisabled;
    string DisabledMessage;
}
```

You then do all the logic in the service layer and your view deals with the returned model appropriately.

Comment: Thank you, this is the approach I think I am going to take.